# The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching the profile '*' and identity '*'

Tags: iphone, provisioning, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am trying to test my iPhone app on a real device. It was working before, and now it is not??? I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching the profile '*' and identity '*'
```

I have tried deleting all profiles and certificates, and starting over. I have tried cleaning the project, restarting everything...etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is probably because you are mixing up the 'Distribution Provisoning Profile' with the 'Development Provisioning Profile'.

Comment: Hi again I dont understand what is going on, i have this same problem

Comment: I have in the "Code Signing Identity" 
Debug                        iPhone Developer
    Any ios sdk              iPhone Developer.
Distribution for testing     iPhone Distribution
    Any ios sdk              iPhone Distribution:my name and prof id
Release                      iPhone Distribution:my name and prof id
    Any ios sdk              iPhone Distribution:my name and prof id
Could you help me?

Comment: @Evaristoyok
Even if you choose "iPhone distribution" for the code signing identity, you may still have "iPhone developer" set for "any iOS SDK" (expand "code signing identity"). This is what messed things up in my case.