# Code Sign error: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching the profile 'submitsearch' and identity 'iPhone Developer

Tags: xcode

I am trying to upload my app to. After tip Archive,it shows :Code Sign error: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching the profile 'submitsearch' and identity 'iPhone Developer.

Which step may be wrong?

thanks

Comment: It can be happen due to many reasons : You can check [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi/12294275#12294275) in this Question. Hope It may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

More than one thing can cause this problem:

- Wrong profile/certificate used
- Wrong export password
- Expired certificate/profile
- **Apple changed something on their side**

I find the best way to fix it is generating both certificate and profile again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is due to not attaching key to p12 file.

for windows I simply run following command in openSSL:

```
pkcs12 -export -inkey privatekey.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12
```

Its work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the solution on this link :

[Default keychain problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041523/the-default-keychain-doesnt-have-an-identity-matching-the-profile-and-ident)

You just have to make a difference between the Distribution Provisoning Profile and the Development Provisioning Profile.

[The Main Difference between Distrib and Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669019/iphone-development-what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-and-distributi)

Comment: I am sure that I indeed get the Distribution Provisoning Profile .

Comment: And so you added your device including the required provisioning profile in the organizer?

Comment: No,the distribution provisoning profile doesn't include the my device. I just want to submit my app to appstore, I followed this website. However,failed. http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442